# ListView item onItemClick is being called via onClickListener

Tags: java, android

In My list i have items that has a button inside of it, currently whenever i try clicking the button it also triggers the onItemClick. The code below is inside the getView

```
holder.btnAdd.setTag(tg);       
    holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            Toast.makeText(getParent().getActivity(), "clicked this button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
```

Here is the onItemClick , this is placed outside the adapter.

```
HorizontalListView hlv = (HorizontalListView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    GalleryAdapter ga = new GalleryAdapter(offerItemDetailsFragment,
            result);
    ga.setListView(hlv);
    hlv.setAdapter(ga);
    hlv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             RelatedOffer relOffer = (RelatedOffer) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: interesting, even i removed the OnClickListener, and clicked the Button it still calls the onItemClick event.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an `OnItemClickListener` with lists that have internal clickable elements without having this effect. Instead, try adding an `OnClickListener` to the root layout of your row and execute your item click logic there.

Comment: root layout of the Adapter?

Comment: im afraid i did that before, that is why i moved it inside the getView

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You are going to have two click events now in your getView. One for the button, and now one for the row attached to the root view of your row layout.

Comment: I know i didn't put it there since i am testing all the possibilities, right now i am having one onClick inside the adapter while checking which id to triger

Comment: That does not work for anonymous `OnClickListeners`. You need to do two separate ones. The event is only fired for the view it is attached to, so checking the id is pointless.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51315/discussion-between-dcharms-and-mikedroid)

Comment: +1 this answer yet still needs some info, discussing. Thaanks guys.

Comment: Basically, my Listview is a subclass of AdapterView, and everytime i scroll horizontally, onClickListener is still being triggered, even if i do have a separate id under onClick

Answer (score 0):

If you have button at yours list than try to retrieve id of the button and than have a click listener with respect to the button or else write listener for the button at custom adapter if you have  a custom adapter!!

please visit **http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html**  hope it will help you.

suppose you have yours holder as follows

```
static class UserHolder {
  TextView textName;
  TextView textAddress;
  TextView textLocation;
  Button btnEdit;
  Button btnDelete;
 }
```

with respect to this try to write getView as follows

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  UserHolder holder = null;

  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
   holder = new UserHolder();
   holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   holder.textAddress = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   holder.textLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
   holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
  }
  User user = data.get(position);
  holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
  holder.textAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
  holder.textLocation.setText(user.getLocation());
  holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Edit button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  return row;

 }
```

**so yours custom adapter can look like**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
 Context context;
 int layoutResourceId;
 ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

 public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
   ArrayList<User> data) {
  super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
  this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
  this.context = context;
  this.data = data;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  UserHolder holder = null;

  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
   holder = new UserHolder();
   holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   holder.textAddress = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   holder.textLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
   holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
  }
  User user = data.get(position);
  holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
  holder.textAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
  holder.textLocation.setText(user.getLocation());
  holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Edit button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  });
  return row;

 }

 static class UserHolder {
  TextView textName;
  TextView textAddress;
  TextView textLocation;
  Button btnEdit;
  Button btnDelete;
 }
}
```

**Read more: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html#ixzz2zm0i96yo**

Comment: i did write an anonymous inner class for the onClickListener, still

Comment: hi the answer is updated please visit http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html